# console.log output

Tags: solidity, hardhat, console, smart-contract

I'm running a contract on alchemy node, how can I see the output of `console.log()`? (the console.log() output doesn't appear on the terminal where i'm running js script via hardhat. i'm  on goerli via Alchemy)

```
import "hardhat/console.sol";
contract BookStore {
 function hello() external {
    console.log("hello");}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs are going to show up in the terminal where your hardhat node is running

EDIT : Oh my bad, you're  on goerli. Console.log() is a dev feature that's not available on any live network, you'd need to use an hardhat local network to use it.